# How can i update the record in dropbox programatically in android?

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am integrating dropbox to my android app its working fine but, i am facing the one problem .I am insert the one record programatically record inserted dropbox its worked fine .

How to update data in dropbox.

I am using the following code to insert dropbox

```
    DbxFields taskFields = new DbxFields();
    taskFields.set("completed", false);
    taskFields .set("taskname", taskName);
    taskFields.set("taskaddress", taskaddress);
    taskFields.set("taskphone", taskPhone);
    taskFields.set("created", new Date());
    mTable.insert(taskFields);
    mDatastore.sync();
```

i dn't know how to update the above inserted record.please guide me anyone know.Adavance thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the following example and let's assume that you want to change the completed-value of the **task with the name XYZ** to *true*.

```
    DbxTable mTable = store.getTable("YOUR_TABLE_NAME");
    DbxFields mQueryFields = new DbxFields();
    mQueryFields.set("taskname", "XYZ");
    try {
        QueryResult mResults = mTable.query(mQueryFields);
        Iterator<DbxRecord> iter = mResults.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            DbxRecord record = iter.next();
            DbxFields mUpdateFields = new DbxFields();
            mUpdateFields.set("completed", true);
            record.setAll(mUpdateFields);
        }
    } catch (DbxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    store.sync();
```

**Note:** Since I'm using a while-loop this code would change the completed-value of all tasks named "XYZ"

### Edit

If you try to edit only one property there's actually no need to create sa new `DbxFields`object, just call this:

```
record.set(PROPERTY, VALUE);
story.sync();
```

Comment: thanks for ur advice but what are the updateFields.please tell me

Comment: The `updateFields` are basically the same as your `taskFields`, you just set the column-name and the value. If the column exists already it will replace the value. In this example it'll be changed from `false` `true`.

Comment: record.setAll(mUpdateFields); this method i am using not inserted to the dropbox .so please provide the totalfiedlsdata